# Increase number in string in bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

How can I increment the value of an int in a string ?

Say I have foo-815-bar. I'd like to have foo-815-bar.
foo and bar can be constants (although if bar can be an unknown variable, it would be preferable), and 815 is a variable. It's a 3 digit number that is to be incremented, so that foo-123-bar would return foo-124-bar.

Comment: Have a look to "set" with expressions and to "for /l in ('string')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
@echo off
set "string=foo-123-bar"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%i in ("%string%") do (
    set "pre=%%i"
    set /a number=%%j+1
    set "post=%%k"
)
set "string=%pre%-%number%-%post%"
echo %string%
```

.. output is:

```
foo-124-bar
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. One last thing, would it be possible to keep the number of digits ? Such that 10 would be 010, and 3 would become 003 ? Thanks

Comment: Yes `set "number=00%number:~-3%"`

Comment: And how to make it a function ? So that maybe I can write set string =f string

Comment: sorry, you can't have function in cmd shell, this is not `C#`.

Comment: I mean something like call:function string, and a label :function. I'm not sure of the syntax, but I've seen it used

Comment: Well this was exactly it, I was able to do it on my own. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started... you might have to place this inside a loop depending on your needs.

```
@echo off
set myFoo=foo-
set myBar=-bar
set /a myIncrementor=123
echo %myFoo%%myIncrementor%%myBar%
set /a myIncrementor+=1
echo %myFoo%%myIncrementor%%myBar%
```